# Working with expression ASTs

Tags: design-patterns, expression, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there any best practice when working with ASTs?
I have a parsed expression AST. ConstantExpression, BinaryExpression etc. 
I want to populate a GUI-dialog with information from the AST, and it's here where I get kinda confused because my code gets pretty messy.

Example:

```
expression = "Var1 > 10 AND Var2 < 20"
```

I want to populate two textboxes with value 10 resp. 20 from the AST.
What I'm doing now is a recursive method that checks for correct child expression-types (with .Net Is-operator) and acts accordingly and the code is really "smelly" :)

Is there any design pattern, like Visitor or such, that makes this somewhat easier/more readable/maintainable ?

Comment: Regarding your comment. I am not sure I understand the difficulty you're describing. What kind of expressions are not allowed? Anyway, my point is that the two apporaches that describe can be used for all kinds of manipulations/validations that you want to perform on the tree. You just need to add a new method (in the first approach) with appropriate parameters or define a new subclass of visitor (in the second approach) with appropriate fields.

Comment: Here's what I mean.
  exp1 = "1+1"
  exp2 = "Var1 > 10 AND Var2 < 20"

With your solution I would get two integers back from both expressions BUT the first expression is not of correct type for my application. The GUI im populating can only work with certain type of expressions NOT every type of expression that contain (somwhere in the tree) two integers.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are specifically trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Best practices for working with ASTs are:

- Get good parsers to help you build the ASTs from some kind of grammar description
- Get a good library to help you walk the AST to collect/modify the AST

For serious work with ASTs, this is best done by using a package designed to generate and manipulate ASTs. Often such packages include a lot of additional support, such as pattern matching and/or AST rewriting using source-to-source transformations.

Here are several:

- [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org)
- [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) (my product)
- [TXL](http://www.txl.ca)

[This example](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html) shows how to build and manipulate ASTs using only BNF, patterns, and source-to-source transformations.

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers solve this problem by using either

- Method overriding
- Visitor

Here are is how you'd go about collecting all constant value (literals) that appears in your expression into a `List` of integers. Calling code can then populate textboxes with values from this list.

**Method overriding**

The top-most AST class defines an abstract method which is overridden at subclasses.

```
class AstNode {
  .. // Some stuff
  public abstract void collectValues(List<Integer> ints);
}

class ConstantExpression : AstNode {
  private int value;
  .. // Some stuff
  public override void collectValues(List<Integer> ints) { ints.Add(value); }
}

 class BinaryExpression : AstNode {
   private AstNode left;
   private AstNode right;
   .. // Some stuff
   public override void collectValues(List<Integer> ints) { 
      left.collectValues(ints); 
      right.collectValues(ints); 
   }
}

class Identifier : AstNode {
  .. // Some stuff
  public override void collectValues(List<Integer> ints) { 
     // do nothing!
  }
}
```

**Visitor**

Same program but written using Visitors.

```
class Visitor {
   public abstract void visit(ConstantExpression e);
   public abstract void visit(BinaryExpression e);
   public abstract void visit(Identifier e);
}

class AstNode {
  .. // Some stuff
  public abstract void accept(Visitor v);
}

class ConstantExpression : AstNode {
  public int value;
  .. // Some stuff
  public override void accept(Visitor v) { v.visit(this); }
}

 class BinaryExpression : AstNode {
   private AstNode left;
   private AstNode right;
   .. // Some stuff
  public override void accept(Visitor v) { 
     left.accept(v); 
     right.accept(v); 
     v.visit(this); 
  }
}

class Identifier : AstNode {
  .. // Some stuff
  public override void accept(Visitor v) { v.visit(this); }
}


class ValueCollector : Visitor {
  public List<Integer> ints = ...;

   public void visit(ConstantExpression e) { ints.Add(e.value); }
   public void visit(BinaryExpression e) { }
   public void visit(Identifier e) { }
}
```

Comment: It's a nice solution, but not that "safe" that I wanted. That solution only collects values. 
Eg. "expression: 1+1" would work with your solution but that kind of expression isn't allowed etc.